# using spring with jsf

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I want to use spring with jsf in my project. So how can I use both in my project , can anyone 
can give an example how I can use both in my project.

Comment: There are too many examples out there of JSF and Spring.  What part of spring do you want to use?

Comment: @Nix  : I want to integrate both ,just i need an example

Comment: [This](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/ch12.html) might help you figure it out.

Comment: Spring consists of many modules. Do you just want to use Spring's Dependency injection container or are you looking to integrate Spring MVC and JSF?

Comment: @meriton: I want to use Spring Dependency injection container

Comment: I don't understand why it is marked as *Not a real question*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Design point of view**

---

You can use JSF as front part `view` , and use Spring at Service and DAO layer of app.

**Implementation point of view**

---

in `web.xml`

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>           
        classpath:application-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

`faces-config.xml` add variable resolver

```
<application>
        <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
        <variable-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver</variable-resolver>
 </application>
```